# ¿Còmo filtrar y comparar 2 tablas en PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas

Buen día. Como podría hacer desde pandas lo siguiente: Tengo 2 tablas, df1 es el inventario mìnimo y df2 lo disponible en 'almacenes'. Deseo que se genere una tercera tabla (FINAL) que solo filtre el resultado de df2 siempre y cuando la columna CANT solo arroje la cantidad que supere al mínimo indicado en df1. GRACIAS

df1:

```
|COD | FRUTA |  CANT|
|----|-------|------|
|16  | manzana|  12 |
|51  | pera   |  5  |
|26  |  uva   |  8  |
```

df2:

```
|COD | FRUTA |  CANT|
|----|-------|------|
|16  | manzana | 10|
|51  |  pera   | 23
|26  |  uva    |  5
|16  |  manzana| 20
|51  | manzana | 18
|26  | uva     | 18
|16  |  uva    | 12|
|51  |pera     |  4|
|26  |uva      |  3|
```

Final:

```
|COD | FRUTA   | CANT|
|----|---------|-----|
|16  |  manzana|  20 |
|16  |  manzana|  18 |
|51  |  pera   |  23 |
|26  |  uva    |  18 |
|26  |  uva    |  12 |
```

Después de definir df1 y df2 al hago esto:....
df2['cant']=df2['cant']>df1['cant']

Comment: Mi pregunta es ¿por qué utilizas la columna `fecha` si lo que quieres es comparar la columna `cant`?

Comment: Prueba  con `final = df2[df2["CANT"]>df1["CANT"]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes comenzar haciendo un `left join` para relacionar las dos tablas por `COD`:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1[['COD', 'CANT']], on='COD', how='left', suffixes=['', '_y'])
```

Y luego finalmente hacemos fácilmente una selección por el valor de `CANT`:

```
final = df3.loc[df3.CANT > df3.CANT_y]
```

Comment: Gracias @patricio Moracho Tu ayuda me fue muy útil.

Comment: Y qué sucedería si añadimos un producto que no figura en la tabla df1 como "bananas"..... final = df3.loc[df3.CANT > df3.CANT_y] ...........No puede darse el caso que un valor sea mayor a la 'nada' porque me ha sucedido y simplemente lo deja en blanco, aunque yo preferiría que colocara el valor de 'bananas'.

Comment: Pues imagino que podrías hacer algo así `df3.CANT > df3.CANT_y.fillna(0)` o bien `df3.CANT > df3["CANT_y"].fillna(0)`